# Avoiding "?" symbols in string column

Tags: sql-server

In my contact table, I'm getting `?` symbols in *LastName*. How can I avoid that?

```
FirstName   MiddleName     LastName
Bjorn       Erik           N?ss
Gunn                       Gjos?ther
Oystein     Larsen         Indrev?r
Louise      Tulle          Pr?strud
```

Comment: Hi, Where do you see that output? What is the table definition? What is your query?

Answer (score 12):

You need to ensure the *LastName* column is a Unicode type, for example nvarchar(30), and use the N prefix on any literal strings you use in insert/update/merge statements. (Alternatively, you could use a non-Unicode type with a code page that supports all the characters you need.)

SQL Server replaces characters it cannot convert with the ? symbol.

See [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms186939.aspx)

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

The code page is determined by the collation. Taking `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS` as an example:

```
SELECT FH.[description]
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() AS FH
WHERE FH.name = N'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS';
```

Output:

```
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, 
    kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data  
SQL Server Sort Order 106 on Code Page 1251 for non-Unicode Data
```

[Code page 1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (used for non-Unicode data in that collation) does not have the `æ` character, so:

```
SELECT 'Gjøsæther' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS;
```

Produces:

```
Gjos?ther
```

Notice that as well as the `?`, the `ø` character was translated to `o`.

The question does not state which collation the instance/database/column is using, but it seems very likely it is the wrong one for your data.

More general information:

[Data Types (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187752.aspx#Anchor_0)
[Collation and Unicode Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms143726.aspx)